# Wait for Async method calls in c#

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service as below

```
public bool RefreshDB()
{
   if (twcPMRefresh())
            status = true;
   if (twcCommonRefresh())
            status = true;
}
```

The logic inside the methods twcPMRefresh() and twcCommonRefresh() is asynchronous and hence I want to wait till 'twcPMRefresh' exceution is finished
execution and then invoke twcCommonRefresh. Both the methods are more are less like below.

```
public bool twcPMRefresh()
{
     tweets=await
         (from tweet in GetTwitterContext(localProxyIP,fCode).Status
         where tweet.Type == StatusType.User &&
         select tweet)
     .ToListAsync();
     --use 'tweets' list to insert in database
 }
```

Can please assist on this. Thanks!!

Comment: You could use the TPL and make use of the `Task.ContinueWith` call.

Comment: Task continueWith is suggested in RefreshDB() method? I tried the below way but still no luck. Is there anything wrong in the syntax.               var firstTask = new Task(() =>twcPMRefresh());
            var secondTask = firstTask.ContinueWith((t) => twcCommonRefresh());
            
            firstTask.Start();

Comment: It would be awesome if you showed the signatures for the two methods.

Comment: Hi @Enigmativity, added the signatures of the two methods.

Comment: @dotnetdeveloper - That code doesn't even compile. Can you please show the correct signatures?

Comment: The actual code includes so many references, variables etc. Cannot paste everything.

Comment: @dotnetdeveloper - Then perhaps delete the question because the code you're posting doesn't make sense. If you're going to ask a decent question then you have to spend the time to do it properly. You need to post a [mcve] according to the help center.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `await async` method:

Assuming your `twcPMRefresh()` and `twcCommonRefresh()` methods are both ASYNC you can write it like this:

```
public async bool RefreshDB()
{
   if (await twcPMRefresh())
       status = true;
   if (await twcCommonRefresh())
       status = true;
}
```

your method `RefreshDB()` can now be called either way:

```
bool result = RefreshDB().Result()
bool result = await RefreshDB(); //Needs an async Method or a task to be used.
```